# Cardinality of the set of all infinite monotonically decreasing sequences of naturals

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> Find the cardinality of the set of all infinite monotonically decreasing sequences of naturals.

I think it's $\aleph_0$. I marked this set in $A$, and said that $\forall n\in\Bbb N \ (n,n,n,...)\in A$, Therefore, $\aleph_0\le|A|$. But I'm not sure how to show that $|A|\le\aleph_o$. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A monotonically non-increasing sequence of natural numbers is eventually constant, so it is completely identified by specifying the finite initial subsequence up to the point at which it becomes constant. There are only countably many finite sequences of natural numbers.

Answer (score -2):

> Find the cardinality of the set of all infinite monotonically **decreasing** sequences of naturals.

There are no infinite monotonically decreasing sequences of naturals, since the natural numbers are well-ordered. Thus, the set of all such sequences is empty, and has cardinality $0$.

You seem to have gotten *decreasing* mixed up with *non-increasing*.

Comment: This terminology is not universally agreed upon. Some authors will write "decreasing" and "strictly decreasing", others "non-increasing" and "decreasing". I doubt that the OP meant strictly decreasing, though.

Comment: I see your point, but I would add to @MarioCarneiro's point that the OP explicitly uses constant sequences for his injection, so he obviously *intended* his terminology to include all non-increasing sequences even the OP's term was wrong.

Comment: @almagest: His intent might not match the intent of whoever posed the problem to him.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point, but I still agree with MarioCarneiro. BTW, I did not make the downvote which I see has just appeared.